# 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: angularjs, laravel

getting an error when i try to update .... PUT http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/task 405 (Method Not Allowed), can someone help?

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
     $currentUser = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();

     $task = $currentUser->tasks()->find($id);

     if(!$task)
     throw new NotFoundHttpException;

      $task->fill($request->all());

      if($task->save())
            return $this->response->noContent();
      else
         return $this->response->error('could_not_update_task', 500);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `methodNotAllowed` exception indicates that a route doesn't exist for the HTTP method you are requesting.

this route `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/task` looks like a store route

Update will be like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/task/1`

**so make sure you have added the route for method**

Comment: Not that the route doesn't exist, it's that the HTTP verb being used to access the route is incorrect, i.e. using `POST` instead of `GET`

Comment: Hare is my angular service   im using restangular customPUT,                                                                                                                                                   
              function update(taskId, data, onSuccess, onError) {

        Restangular.one("api/task").customPUT(data, taskId).then(function (response) {
       // Restangular.one(data, taskId).customPUT(data, 'api/task').then(function (response) {

            onSuccess(response);

        }, function (response) {

            onError(response);

        }
        );

    }

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys for the help, after hack and hack, I realized my Restangular.one("api/task").customPUT(data, taskId).then(function (response)  FUNCTION was not receiving data, so PUT was hitting on the api route with no data causing the not allowed method error.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: Since HTML forms only support POST and GET, PUT and DELETE methods will be spoofed by automatically adding a _method hidden field to your form. ([Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#opening-a-form))

Can you use `GET` or `POST` method?

or

`{!! Form::open(array('url' => '/', 'method' => 'PUT', 'class'=>'col-md-12')) !!}
.... wathever code here
{!! Form::close() !!}`

something like this. Hope this help

EDIT: I just saw your route and your controller. It expects a slug or unique identifier (which in case is id), so your route must look something like this

`Route::put('/api/task/{id}', 'YourController@update');`

This gives your controller the unique identifier you want.

Comment: here is my route for put.................$api->put('task/{id}', 'App\Api\V1\Controllers\TaskController@update,     and my angular service here .......function update(taskId, data, onSuccess, onError) {

        Restangular.one("api/task").customPUT(data, taskId).then(function (response) {
       // Restangular.one(data, taskId).customPUT(data, 'api/task').then(function (response) {

            onSuccess(response);

        }, function (response) {

            onError(response);

        }
        );

    }